# Volume of water in container

Tags: calculus, volume

Volume of a container is $\frac{4 \pi}{3}$. Water can flow in and out of container.The volume of water in container is given by: $g(t), 0 \leq t \leq 4$, where $t$ is time in hours and $g(t)$ is measured in $m^3$. The rate of change of the volume of water in the container is: $g'(t)= 0.9 - 2.5 cos(0.4 t^2)$.

a) The volume of water is increasing when $p < t < q$. Find $p$ and $q$. During that interval the volume of water increases by  k $ m^3$. Find k.

When $t =0$, the volume of water in the container is $2.3 m^3$. The container is never completely full of water during 4 hour period.

b) Find the minimum volume of empty space in the container during the 4 hour period.

I did part a) and found that p= 1.733874  and q = 3.56393, so volume increased by $ g(q) - g(p)= \int_{p}^{q} g'(t) dt = 3.7454$ $m^3$ during that period. 
I don't know how to do part b). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part b is just asking to find the volume of air in the container at a certain time. Let $h(t)$ be the volume occupied by air such that
$$
h(t) = \frac{4\pi}{3} - g(t).
$$
Notice that the extrema of $h$ occur at the extrema of $g$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I have found that g(t) is maximum when x = 1.733874, but then I can't find integral of g'(t) in order to find g(t) and g(1.733874).

Comment: Don't worry about finding the integral of $g$, it involves the Fresnel integral. You can rewrite $h$ as
$$
h(t) = \frac{4\pi}{3} - \int_0^t g'(t) \, \mathrm{d}t - g(0)
$$
and find the volume as you did with $g(q) - g(p).$ Also, if $g'$ is increasing from $p$ to $q$, would it be $p$ or $q$ when $g$ is maximum?

Comment: I found that integral of g'(t) from t=0 to t=1.733874 is  - 2.187, what means that volume of water decreased, so volume is 2.3 - 2.187 = 0.113. Then, from t=1.733874 to t=3.56393 volume increases by 3.7454 so it will be 0.113+3.7454=3.8584. Finally, integral from t=3.56393 to t=4 is  - 0.4678, so volume is 3.8584 - 0.4678= 3.3906. Maximum volume is 3.8584, and therefore minimum empty space is 0.33. I hope these calculations are correct.

Comment: Looks good to me! And thank you for my first gold badge, I won't be forgetting this one :)

Comment: Thank you for help :)